# Rest API Calling Using Feign Client Vs RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, feign, spring-resttemplate

I want to call an API of the Spring Boot application from the my MVC Spring application. Is Feign Client or RestTemplate better for this API call and Why is it better?

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884362/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-feign-over-resttemplate

Comment: There is advantages and disadvantages of using feign over RestTemplate. I want to know about the most suitable one for my senario. also I'm not using microservice.

Comment: If you are not using microservice architecture, then simple RESTTemplate call should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

RestTemplate and FeignClient are both popular tools for calling REST APIs in Spring Boot applications.
Both have their own strengths and weaknesses, so the best choice for you will depend on your specific needs.

RestTemplate is a more general-purpose HTTP client, which can be used to make any type of HTTP request. It is also more flexible than FeignClient, allowing you to have more control over the request and response process. However, this flexibility can also make RestTemplate more complex to use.

FeignClient is a declarative web service client that makes it easier to write web service clients. It uses a simple interface to define the REST API that you want to call, and FeignClient will generate the code to make the HTTP requests for you. This can make FeignClient much easier to use than RestTemplate, especially for complex APIs.